# Nuget: detect unresolved package dependency constraints with nuget.exe?

Tags: nuget

When using the NuGet Package Manager from Visual Studio, it will warn if there are unresolved package dependency constraints detected.

For example, when the packages.config contains:

```
<packages>
  <package id="PackageA" version="1.0.0" />
  <package id="PackageB" version="3.0.0"/>
</packages>
```

But PackageB requires version 2.0.0 for PackageA instead of version 1.0.0, then a warning will be raised. This is very useful to know in our case.

Does anyone know how to get such checks and warnings when using the CLI, e.g. `nuget.exe install` or `nuget.exe restore`?
I tried different `-DependencyVersion` options, but PackageB just always installs without any warnings when using the CLI unfortunately.